# Rails - Application layout with SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, ruby-on-rails-3

**Hello**, all my fellow coders!
I've got a problem *ohh chok!*.. :P 
Now my problem i that i'm trying to make a design for a bigger site, it's going good. Until i should make the content/news slider. It should take data from multiple tables and returning to  the application.html.erb.

So it is take reviews and announcements just the latest 5 and order it after latest created. and then give it to me in the application.html.erb.. *(Rails 3.0.0.beta4)*

hope you guys understands me.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question (or be more specific)?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is quite difficult to explain, and specially when i am so bad to english as i am.

But i'll try.
I use nifty:layout to the layout part, so i have created a custom application.html.erb file, in that i have a slider to content where it is rolling news, reviews and stuff like that. From multiple tables. So my question is how to take the data out from my tables(see: tables(there are a few) ) and then take the data out. like with posts in @posts = Posts.find(..), you get the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the latest 5 for all the models, then put all records on an array, sort the array and take the first 5 elements.

```
# consider moving .order('date desc').limit(5) to a named scope or a module
announcements = Announcement.order('date desc').limit(5)
posts = Post.order('date desc').limit(5)
monkeys = Monkey.order('date desc').limit(5)
# .. add others here

elements = (announcements + posts + monkeys).sort_by(&:date).reverse[1..5]
```

The variable `elements` will have the 5, if they exist.

Note: I'm assuming that all your models have a method called "date". You can change it to date_created or whatever.

You can put this code on several places, but I think the best one would be a "home" controller, created specifically for rendering the home page. The elements would be calculated on its show action.

Comment: Hey thanks, but you didn't give me answer on my last part in the question, about where to put it? Wich controller. And no, i don't have a date method?

Comment: sure - a home controller is your best bet IMHO. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it's more performant to use this syntax, instead of the one from egarcia:

```
elements = (announcements | posts | monkeys).sort_by(&:date).reverse[1..5]
```

if you need to use this code in several pages (for example in sidebars), then the best way could be to write an helper (say: last_items)